# How can I handle new relation model records in Yii2's main Activeform model?

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-model

I have two models in Yii ... User and Languages ... Languages is the languages a user can speak.

I have an update view to edit all the user staff, and I would like to have an only form to handle the POST in the controller.

The controller view is:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    // in this model I can access $model->languages to get all the languages of the user

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

So the form view would be:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form_cliente']);

echo "<h2>User data</h2>";
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput();
echo $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput();
echo $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput();

echo "<h3>Languages</h3>";
foreach ($model->languages as $l) {
   echo $form->field($l, 'user.languages.language')->textInput();
   echo $form->field($l, 'user.languages.level')->textInput();
}

ActiveForm::end();
```

The problem is that the "loop" is not working since I don't know how to access to the related model records.

And also, I'd like to have just one ActiveForm to handle:

- the data from the User model
- the data from the Language model (modification of languages records)
- the possible new data from a new language insertion

Comment: you should narrow down your problem to a specific portion where you are having problem along with the current implementation of the code you are using, you should read  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-tabular-input

Comment: I think I have explained myself better :-)

Comment: yes now it explains much better so you are looking to display all the languages a user can speak inside the edit form and able to update it too if you want to change any language, that is now much clear if i understand correctly but what about adding new language do you want to be able to add more languages via the same form? as the current implementation wont allow you to add any new languages BUT change any of the existing.

Comment: if whatever i said is correct i would advise you to use the `select2` with multi-select option `'multiple'=>true`, in this scenario rather than using text inputs, as you can add/remove languages and at the same time display all of them without a `foreach` loop

Comment: also it would be much easier to update them by just doing `Yii::$app->request->post('languages')` and getting the whole array holding the `id` of the languages and, easier to save all of them, rather than searching the user entered language spellings in the db to get the id and then saving the references of ids in the database table

Comment: hope it helps you out , go on with the change and post back into your question if you run into problems we will sort it out

Comment: I know select2 ... my example here was to illustrate the problem, but my models have currently dozens of fields :-D